# Finally clause of promise never getting executed in Jasmine test

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, angular-promise

I have this jasmine test, and the finally clause on a promise appears to not be getting executed, as I get the error:

```
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0) Service: petsFactory .getPetsAsync() should return a list of pets FAILED
    Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
```

My test file looks like:

```
'use strict';

describe('Service: petsFactory', function () {

  // load the service's module
  beforeEach(module('smokeTestApp'));

  // instantiate service
  var petsFactory;
  beforeEach(inject(function (_petsFactory_) {
    petsFactory = _petsFactory_;
  }));

  describe('.getPetsAsync()', function () {
    it('should return a list of pets', function (done) {

      var testPets = function (pets) {
        expect(Array.isArray(pets)).toBe(true);
      }

      var failTest = function(error) {
        expect(error).toBeUndefined();
      };

      petsFactory
        .getPetsAsync()
        .then(testPets)
        .catch(failTest)
        .finally(done);
    });
  });
});
```

The relevant factory method looks like:

```
var getPetsAsync = function () {
    return $q.when(pets);
};
```

The contents of the pets variable is totally synchronous, the promise is just a wrapper on a synchronous value that is there immediately.

What is going wrong here?

Comment: Is the `then` function invoked? Also, do you inject $q normally in the factory? I had a similar issue in the past because I was meddling with the angular $injector, instead of using the normal injection in controllers/services.

Comment: $q is injected normally. Perhaps then is not being invoked. I just tried throwing an exception in the testPets function, and still got the same error in Jasmine. Though, that would be really bizarre, as I'm using when to wrap a synchronous value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/unit-testing#testing-promises):

> When testing promises, it's important to know that the resolution of
>   promises is tied to the digest cycle. That means a promise's then,
>   catch and finally callback functions are only called after a digest
>   has run. In tests, you can trigger a digest by calling a scope's
>   $apply function. If you don't have a scope in your test, you can
>   inject the $rootScope and call $apply on it. There is also an example
>   of testing promises in the $q service documentation.

So simply inject `$rootScope` and use `$apply`:

```
petsFactory
  .getPetsAsync()
  .then(testPets)
  .catch(failTest)
  .finally(done);

$rootScope.$apply();
```